# "ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns" while trying to apply a new row to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a method that takes some info, puts it into a dict and then converts the dict to a Pandas DataFrame that is then added to a CSV. when this is ran it returns "ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns" I've done quite a bit of tinkering around with this small method and I cannot figure out why this error is being raised

this is the function I'm running:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections_file = "logging.csv"

        self.connections = pd.read_csv(self.connections_file)
   
   def log_incoming_connection(self, client, identification):
        time = "foo"

        data = {'Time': [time],
                'IP': [f"{client.peername}:{str(client.port)}"],
                'FirstByte': [str(identification)],
                }

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        self.connections.loc[len(self.connections)] = df
        self.connections.to_csv(self.connections_file)
```

the CSV file is structured like this and there is data within it other than this header:

`,Time,IP,FirstByte`

if I were to clear the CSV, not have it read on init, and then save the "data" df straight to the CSV it will write to the file correctly. But not again if called later (raises the same error.)

could this be a problem with how I'm choosing to append the main DataFrame? **Pandas has removed the DataFrame.append() method in its latest version** so many resources online don't mention an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to pass `index_col=0` and use a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to assign the new row :

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections_file = "logging.csv"
        self.connections = pd.read_csv(self.connections_file, index_col=0)
   
    def log_incoming_connection(self, client, identification):
        
        data = {'Time': 'foo',
                'IP': f"{client.peername}: {str(client.port)}",
                'FirstByte': str(identification)}
        
        self.connections.loc[len(self.connections)] = pd.Series(data)
        self.connections.to_csv(self.connections_file)
```

Note that you have an (*extra?*) column in your `.csv`. I suppose that this one was made the first time with a `to_csv(index=True)` and I'm not sure if that was on purpose.

```
 ,Time,IP,FirstByte
^------------------
```

Also, if it's just a matter of adding new rows, I suggest to append them with `a` [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections_file = "logging.csv"
   
    def log_incoming_connection(self, client, identification):
        
        data = {
            'Time': "foo",
            'IP': f"{client.peername}:{str(client.port)}",
            'FirstByte': str(identification)
        }
            
        pd.DataFrame([data]).to_csv(self.connections_file,mode="a",header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the new data to a dataframe first. Just add the new row as a tuple.

```
   def log_incoming_connection(self, client, identification):
        time = "foo"

        new_row = (time, f"{client.peername}:{str(client.port)}", str(identification))

        self.connections.loc[len(self.connections)] = new_row
        self.connections.to_csv(self.connections_file)
```